# Disable specific IAP for iPad devices only

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I have submitted an app to the appstore which contains an In-App Purchase for removing ads. However when running on iPad ads are not served due to being in compatibility mode (the app is targeted for iPhone devices only).
So my app got rejected saying "Apps that do not perform as advertised by the developer will be rejected" (Regarding the "Remove Ads" iap)

My question is can I disable this iap (i.e. remove the option from the app's user interface) when running on iPad only? (while on iPhone devices ads will be served and the purchase option will be available)

(I also sent a question to the Apple support team but was hoping someone here already dealt with it and might reply faster)

Comment: You'll probably get faster results if you put this question on Stack Overflow, too.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 yeah but they will probably close it as this is not a code related issue. I've seen similar questions close before on SO and I was sure this is the place for Apple related issues (besides the formal Apple forum)